# Buscador de endereço por CEP em Java

Tags: jsf, java-ee, java

Bom dia, galera!

Tenho um buscador de CEP que não está mais funcionando. Quando uso a URL passando meu CEP ele retorna a consulta. Obrigado desde já pela ajuda!

Eis um [link de exemplo](http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=17514520&formato=xml) para testar a consulta direto no navegador. Aqui está o resultado:

```xml
<webservicecep>
     <resultado>1</resultado>
     <resultado_txt>sucesso - cep completo</resultado_txt>
     <uf>SP</uf>
     <cidade>Marília</cidade>
     <bairro>Vila Romana</bairro>
     <tipo_logradouro>Rua</tipo_logradouro>
     <logradouro>Antônio Pinheiro Faro</logradouro>
</webservicecep>
```

```java
public void encontraCEP() {

    CepWebService cepWebService = new CepWebService(cliente.getCep());

    if (cepWebService.getResultado() == 1) {

        cliente.setLogradouro(cepWebService.getLogradouro());
        cliente.setUf(cepWebService.getEstado());
        cliente.setCidade(cepWebService.getCidade());
        cliente.setBairro(cepWebService.getBairro());
        // cliente.setTipoEndereco(cepWebService.getTipoLogradouro());
    } else {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "Cep não encontraro ou erro no servidor",
                        "Digite os dados manualmente"));
    }
}
```

```java
public class CepWebService {

    private String estado = "";
    private String cidade = "";
    private String bairro = "";
    private String tipoLogradouro = "";
    private String logradouro = "";

    private int resultado = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public CepWebService(String cep) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" + cep
                            + "&formato=xml");

            Document document = getDocumento(url);

            Element root = document.getRootElement();

            for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                Element element = (Element) i.next();

                if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("uf"))
                    setEstado(element.getText());

                if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("cidade"))
                    setCidade(element.getText());

                if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("bairro"))
                    setBairro(element.getText());

                if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("tipo_logradouro"))
                    setTipoLogradouro(element.getText());

                if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("logradouro"))
                    setLogradouro(element.getText());

                if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("resultado"))
                    setResultado(Integer.parseInt(element.getText()));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Document getDocumento(URL url) throws DocumentException {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document = reader.read(url);

        return document;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getTipoLogradouro() {
        return tipoLogradouro;
    }

    public void setTipoLogradouro(String tipoLogradouro) {
        this.tipoLogradouro = tipoLogradouro;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public int getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    public void setResultado(int resultado) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }
}
```

Fiz o seguinte teste. Passei o CEP direto para testar e está retornando resultado no debug.

```java
 public void encontraCEP() {

    CepWebService cepWebService = new CepWebService("17522350");

    if (cepWebService.getResultado() == 1) {

        cliente.setLogradouro(cepWebService.getLogradouro());
        cliente.setUf(cepWebService.getEstado());
        cliente.setCidade(cepWebService.getCidade());
        cliente.setBairro(cepWebService.getBairro());
        //cliente.setTipoEndereco(cepWebService.getTipoLogradouro());
    } else {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Cep não encontraro ou erro no servidor",
                "Digite os dados manualmente"));
    }
}
```

[image: foto do debug]

Meu `CommandButton` está mandando `null` para o método:

```xml
 <p:outputLabel for="cep" value="CEP"  />

                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:inputMask id="cep" mask="99999-999"  size="9"
                                 value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.cep}"       />

                    <p:commandButton value="Buscar Endereço" style=" color: #D20005" >
                       <f:ajax listener="#{cadastroClienteBean.encontraCEP}"  render="@form"
                               event="click"  />
                   </p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Está correto o retorno do serviço. Ele retorna o xml contento o endereço do CEP. Qual o problema que você está enfrentando? PS: Sugiro que para fazer a serialização do xml  você utilize uma API que faz isso pra você, como a xstream (http://x-stream.github.io/).

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra  Ele está caindo direto no else,  retornando a msg que cep não foi encontrado.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Então faz o seguinte, começa vendo se a variável root está obtendo os valores carregados do xml, i.e., se o fluxo de execução está entrando no for. Nunca usei esse SAXReader para serialização, aí não conheço o formato que ele retorna.

Comment: Tem certeza que cliente.getCep() não esta nulo? é a única forma de cair no else, o código esta correto, debug e confere por favor.

Comment: @DilneiCunha A Classe que faz a consulta está funcionando, está retornando o cep. estou fazendo alguma coisa de errada  no método ou na minha passagem da minha pagina.
fiz assim 'CepWebService cepWebService = new CepWebService("17522350");' e retornou cep no debug.

Comment: Testei aqui em uma classe standalone seu código e funciona bem, tem que ir linha a linha no debug para identificar o porque cai no else, ou se não tem outra exception escondida.

Comment: @DilneiCunha editei a pergunta e coloquei o resultado do debug. Obrigado

Comment: Se retornou brother, então ele não cai no else, tem algum outro erro ou problema ?

Comment: É então, estava achando que estava caindo no else, não tinha pesando que poderia ser o getCep que estava null.  Agora preciso ver porque está null o getCep,

Comment: declara um type="submit" no command button e testa por favor.

Comment: @DilneiCunha Deu certo! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.